# Why is my modal not populating all my data

Tags: php, html, jquery, sql, bootstrap-modal

I am new to Bootstrap modals and trying to figure out where I went wrong.

I currently have this piece of code that will display a data table. The first column of the data table has a link to a modal. Upon clicking on the link, the modal displays all my information that I am requesting it to show. At the top of the modal I have an edit button that will allow the user to edit the information. When this modal loads it doesn't load of my of my columns from my database. Below is the modal and column that is not loading:

```
           <div class="col-2 inputRow">
                Description:
            </div>
            <div class="col-10 inputRow">
                <input class="createInput edit_description" id="edit_description" maxlength="100">
            </div>
```

Below is where how my data is being loaded onto my modal:

```
/**
 * Second check to make sure information is most current
 */
function openEditModal(){
  email = CURRENT_USER['email'];
  $.ajax({
   url: './ajax/getData.ajax.php',
   type: 'post',
   data: {
     "getUser": email,
   },
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(response) {
     //Check for timeout
     ajaxTimeoutCheck(response);
     loadEditUser(response);

   }
  });
}

/**
 * Fills in modal to show selected users information
 */
var currentUser;
function loadEditUser(user){
  var currentUser = user;
  console.log(user);
  for (var key in user) {
    if(key != 'uid' && key != 'user' && key != 'updatedby' && key != 'updated' && key != 'global'){
      if(key == "admin"){
            if(user[key] == 1){
              document.getElementById("edit_" + key).checked = true;
            } else {
              document.getElementById("edit_" + key).checked = false;
            }
      } else if (key == "approver"){
        if(user[key] == 1){
          document.getElementById("edit_" + key).checked = true;
        } else {
          document.getElementById("edit_" + key).checked = false;
        }
      } else if(key == "department"){
        document.getElementById("edit_department").value = user[key];
     /*
      * This Section Here Is Not Responsing
      */
      } else if(key == "description"){
        document.getElementById("edit_description").value = user[key];
      } else {
        document.getElementById("edit_" + key).innerHTML = user[key];
      }
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('edit_changeAlt').checked = false;
  removeAlternateEdit();
  $("#editModal").modal();
}
```

My query for the getData.ajax.php file is just:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=$email
```

As you can see I have a console,log() within my code. This actually returns all my information, including the description column but when I click on the modal to load. It will leave description blank. Am I missing something here? Or is my code broken somewhere else that could be causing this?

Comment: You're logging the current user, which is just what you already have in memory. You're passing the response to the function, but it's not part of the definition arguments, so you never use it

Comment: This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Comment: @aynber So what could I add or change to allow me to use it?

Comment: You have `loadEditUser(response);`, so you need to pass the response into `function loadEditUser()` and use that instead of `user`

Comment: @aynber I have updated the question to show what I changed. And description is still not being populated

Comment: This is where you need to try to debug, since we don't know what `user` now contains, nor do we know the elements of your modal. Add a log inside of your `for` loop to see what `key` contains, then make sure it's actually going into the if blocks and see what value it's writing. You can also try doing it manually in your console with `document.getElementById("edit_description").value = 'Testing'`.

Comment: @Cold: The variable `currentUser` isn't used anywhere, so it's not clear why you have that at all.  Have you re-tested since correcting the `concole` typo?  Before correcting that, it would have produced an error on the browser's development console.  Is that error gone now?  Was that error there in the first place?  If not then that would indicate this function isn't being invoked at all and the problem is earlier in the logic.